# read json data and image file as multipart form data in web api 2

Tags: forms, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, multipart

I want to post mutipart form  data like below to a WEB API 2 controller. My data will have JSON and Image file.  Please help me understand how the c# api controller code will be for the below data.

At present I am getting error  at `Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);`:

> Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete

```cs
var uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Userimage/");
Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadPath);
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

// Files
//
foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
    Debug.WriteLine("File path: " + file.LocalFileName);
}

// Form data
//
foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
{
    foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
    }
}
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="modelclass"
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "MessageID": 1,
  "SenderID": 2,
  "userType": "sample string 3",
  "msgCategory": "sample string 4",
  "msgContent": "sample string 5",
  "msgDistributedTo": "sample string 6"
}
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="bg4.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\Lenovo1\Pictures\bg4.jpg*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do this few months ago and ended up with the following code:

```
if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Media type not supported");
}

var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
await request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

A possible issue with your code is that you try to create a directory that should already exist.
Try as well to have a content type check at the beginning of your code.